# .NET 8.0 WebAPI/Swagger Docker Refused to connect

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, swagger, .net-8.0, asp.net-core-8

I migrated my application to .NET 8.0, ran it locally and it works perfectly.

Then I created an image, the container. As a result, the page that was working before now returns a "1.2.3.4 refused to connect."

Before, when I was in .NET 7.0, the API worked.

My basic DockerFile

```bash
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
 
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
 
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0

WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod -R 755 /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapi.dll"]
```

My api runs on port 8860

```
49de1a3ce47c   myapi   "dotnet myapi.dll"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes          0.0.0.0:8860->80/tcp, :::8860->80/tcp
```

Logs:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

Comment: Your app logs indicate its listening on port 8080 within the container. However, in your Docker configuration, you've mapped the host port 8860 to the container port 80.

Comment: @DenisMicheal how to force listening to port 80?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 8 ASP.NET Core Docker images have a breaking change - [Default ASP.NET Core port changed from 80 to 8080](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port):

> The default ASP.NET Core port configured in .NET container images has been updated from port 80 to 8080.
> We also added the new `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS` environment variable as a simpler alternative to `ASPNETCORE_URLS`.

> ##### Previous behavior
>
> Prior to .NET 8, you could run a container expecting port 80 to be the default port and be able to access the running app.
> For example, running the following command allowed you to access the app locally at port 8000, which is mapped to port 80 in the container:
> `docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 <my-app>`

So you need either to change port mapping `8860:8080` or change the port for the container (for example by passing `-e ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80` argument to `docker run` or adding `ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80` after `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0`).